# want to remove this bullet in front of these labels of highcharts graph

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

i am using highcharts solid gauge. below is sample i have created 
[image: high chart solid gauge]

now i want to remove these grey bullets as these are not coming in my local but in test its there, i havn't got anything helpful from api. here are options passing to this.and thus i am not sure what i am missing can anyone guide me as i have tried looking into api for solid gauge but i am not sure which option is there to help me

```
options() {
  return {
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    chart: {
      type: "solidgauge",
    },

    title: {
      text: "",
      style: {
        fontSize: "24px"
      }
    },
    legend: {
      layout: "horizontal",
      align: "right",
      itemDistance: 100,
      verticalAlign: "middle",
      itemMarginTop: 5,
      itemStyle: {
        fontSize: "28px",
      },
      itemMarginBottom: 5,
      labelFormatter: function() {
        const formattedTotal = Number(
          this.userOptions.data[0].total
        ).toLocaleString("en-US", {
          minimumFractionDigits: 0,
          maximumFractionDigits: 0
        });

        return (
          '<span style="text-weight:bold;color:' +
          this.userOptions.data[0].color +
          '">' +
          this.name +
          '</span><br/><span style="text-align: center">' +
          formattedTotal +
          "</span>"
        );
      },
      symbolWidth: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      backgroundColor: "none",
      shadow: false,
      style: {
        fontSize: "16px"
      },
      useHTML: true,
      pointFormat:
        '<table><tr><td style="text-align: center"><span style="font-size: 14px">{series.name}</span><br><span style="font-size:22px; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold">{point.y}%</span></td></tr></table>',
      positioner: function(labelWidth) {
        return {
          x: (this.chart.chartWidth - labelWidth - 600) / 2,
          y: this.chart.plotHeight / 2 - 15
        };
      }
    },

    pane: {
      startAngle: 0,
      endAngle: 360,
      background: [
        {
          // Track for Move
          outerRadius: "112%",
          innerRadius: "88%",
          backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(this.graphColors && this.graphColors[0])
            .setOpacity(0.3)
            .get(),
          borderWidth: 0
        },
        {
          // Track for Exercise
          outerRadius: "87%",
          innerRadius: "63%",
          backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(this.graphColors && this.graphColors[1])
            .setOpacity(0.3)
            .get(),
          borderWidth: 0
        },
        {
          // Track for Stand
          outerRadius: "62%",
          innerRadius: "38%",
          backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(this.graphColors && this.graphColors[2])
            .setOpacity(0.3)
            .get(),
          borderWidth: 0
        }
      ]
    },

    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      lineWidth: 0,
      tickPositions: [],
    },

    plotOptions: {
      solidgauge: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        linecap: "round",
        stickyTracking: false,
        rounded: true
      }
    },

    series: [
      {
        name: "Passerby",
        showInLegend: true,
        data: [
          {
            color: this.graphColors && this.graphColors[0],
            radius: "112%",
            innerRadius: "88%",
            y: this.passerby,
            total: this.passerbyTotal
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Visitor",
        showInLegend: true,
        data: [
          {
            color: this.graphColors && this.graphColors[1],
            radius: "87%",
            innerRadius: "63%",
            y: this.visitor,
            total: this.visitorTotal,
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Connected",
        showInLegend: true,
        data: [
          {
            color: this.graphColors && this.graphColors[2],
            radius: "62%",
            innerRadius: "38%",
            y: this.connected,
            total: this.connectedTotal
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just apply a style to the class highcharts creates to hide these markers:

```
.highcharts-legend-item rect {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: right, i have thought about his but problem in my case is it's not getting applied to highcharts component(i tried to write this in my single file as well as App.vue [as i am using vue]) and thus i am helpless to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `highcharts`, but those bullets looks like the work of a `<ul>` element.

You can remove bullets from all `ul` elements using css, like this:

```
ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

See [list-style-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type). Of course it is better to specify the `#id` of the particular `ul` element, but (above) is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to remove legend symbols and keep series markers. As a workaround, you can remove them manually in the chart `load` event callback.

**Code:**

```
chart: {
  type: "solidgauge",
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var chart = this,
        series = chart.series;

      series.forEach(function(serie, i) {
        if (serie.legendSymbol) {
          serie.legendSymbol.destroy()
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e1usLm08/1/

**API:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#destroy